# Exposing WCF for client Scripts from SharePoint 2010

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, jquery, wcf

I am developing a SharePoint 2010 site and in need to access my WCF Web Methods from a client script from SharePoint. I am not sure on how to do this.

Two approaches in my mind are.

1. Add reference of my WCF to SharePoint solution and add a Application page,define Web Method on Application page,which further access my WCF.
2. Somehow (not sure if possible) to directly access WCF Web Methods from client script from SharePoint.

**Important:**
I can not make any changes to web application's web config in production. If required in any of the above approach.

**EDIT**
My WCF service will not be deployed inside SharePoint but independent deployment will be there.

Kindly suggest which would be the best way to access.

Thanks.

Comment: What is you WCF service authentication scheme?

Comment: If will be inheriting from IIS. Anonymous I belive

Answer (score 2):

You can directly access your WCF Web Methods from client script.

http://www.wictorwilen.se/Post/Calling-a-WCF-Service-using-jQuery-in-SharePoint-the-correct-way.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdev/archive/2011/02/22/calling-a-wcf-service-using-jquery-in-sharepoint.aspx

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/anweshi/archive/2010/11/30/calling-wcf-service-using-jquery-in-sharepoint-applications.aspx